# Is listing all products on the homepage's footer making a real difference SEO-wise?

Tags: seo

I'm working on a website on which I am asked to add to the homepage's footer a list of all the products that are sold on the website along with a link to the products' detail pages.

The problem is that there are about 900 items to display.
Not only that doesn't look good but that makes the page render a lot slower.

I've been told that such a technique would improve the website's visibility in Search Engine.
I've also heard that such techniques could lead to the opposite effect: google seeing it as "spam".

My question is: Is listing products of a website on its homepage really efficient when it comes to becoming more visible on search engines?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That technique is called *keyword stuffing* and [Google says](http://www.google.com/support/webmasters/bin/answer.py?answer=66358) that it's not a good idea:

> "Keyword stuffing" refers to the practice of loading a webpage with keywords in an attempt to manipulate a site's ranking in Google's search results. Filling pages with keywords results in a negative user experience, and can harm your site's ranking. Focus on creating useful, information-rich content that uses keywords appropriately and in context.

Now you might want to ask: Does their crawler *really* realize that the list at the bottom of the page is just keyword stuffing? Well, that's a question that only Google could answer (and I'm pretty sure that they don't want to). In any case: Even *if* you could make a keyword stuffing block that is not recognized, they will probably improve they algorithm and -- sooner or later -- discover the truth. My recommendation: Don't do it.

If you want to optimize your search engine page ranking, do it "the right way" and read the [Search Engine Optimization Guide](http://www.google.com/webmasters/docs/search-engine-optimization-starter-guide.pdf) published by Google.

Comment: Thanks for the link, it's going to help me talk about that to my manager.

Answer (score 3):

Google is likely to see a huge list of keywords at the bottom of each page as spam. I'd highly recommend not doing this.

Answer (score 0):

When is it ever a good idea to specify 900 items to a user? good practice dictates that large lists are usually paginated to avoid giving the user a huge blob of stuff to look through at once.

That's a good rule of thumb, if you're doing it to help the user, then it's probably good ... if you're doing it purely to help a machine (ie. google/bing), then it might be a bad idea.

Comment: I totally agree with you on taht point. But my question is more whether or not it actually is efficient to list keywords like that.

Comment: no, it is not efficient at all ... in any way :-) 900 items in a list is unusable by most any person.

Answer (score -2):

You can return different html to genuine users and google by inspecting the [user agent](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/User_agent) of the web request.

That way you can provide the [google bot](http://www.useragentstring.com/pages/Googlebot/) with a lot more text than you'd give a human user.

Update: People have pointed out that you **shouldn't do this**. I'm leaving this answer up though so that people know it's possible but bad.

Comment: Google bot actually can ban your site permanently if you give different content based on whether the client is a bot or a genuine browser.

Comment: Maxim: have you got a link that substantiates this?

Comment: On their homepage, they claim that they don't like it when different content is displayed to search engines than to users: http://www.google.com/support/webmasters/bin/answer.py?answer=66353